# Does Aurora Cluster supports automatic Load Balance of read queries to Aurora Replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Does Aurora RDS Cluster for MySQL support automatic Load Balancing of read queries to Aurora Replicas being created?

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**- as of [08 Sep 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-reader-endpoint-for-amazon-aurora-load-balancing-higher-availability/), Aurora provides a cluster-level **reader endpoint** you can use to load-balance <del>read queries</del> read-only connections across all read replicas in your cluster.

More details are available in the documentation on [Aurora Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Overview.html#Aurora.Overview.Endpoints):

> #### Reader endpoint
>
> Each Aurora DB cluster has a reader endpoint that you can use to connect to one of the Aurora Replicas in your DB cluster. The reader endpoint for a DB cluster load-balances connections across the Aurora Replicas that are available in a DB cluster. As clients request new connections to the reader endpoint, Aurora distributes the connection requests among the Aurora Replicas in the DB cluster. This functionality can help balance your read workload across multiple Aurora Replicas in your DB cluster.

---

**Update**- as of [16 Mar 2021](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/amazon-rds-proxy-adds-read-only-endpoints-for-amazon-aurora-replicas), [RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/) additionally provides [**read-only endpoints**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/rds-proxy.html#rds-proxy-endpoints-reader) you can use to load-balance read-only connections across all read replicas in your Aurora cluster, with additional support for connection pooling / multiplexing and automatic failover.

Comment: Please do note that load balancing is performed across connections and not individual queries. If you wish to load balance on individual queries you'll have to code it yourself (or create a new connection for each query, but that wouldn't be a good idea in most cases).

Comment: You are correct, thanks for the clarification. I've also added a note about read-only endpoints in RDS Proxy which were recently added.